# How to use data binding and UI state in combination?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-livedata, android-databinding, android-viewmodel

I recently read the "Guide to app architecture" and tried to integrate an UI state into my project. I also read that it's necessary to use a method like "distinctUntilChanged". Now I'm wondering how to use UI state in combination with data binding in my project. The problem is, that you have to use either the "collect" method of StateFlow or the "map" method of Transformations to get an isolated StateFlow/LiveData object for using "distinctUntilChanged". You need to use lambdas for these methods and I don't know how to do this in data binding. I also don't think that this is a best practice. So does anyone know if it makes sense to use UI state and data binding in combination and how to achieve this in a best practice way?

Comment: Check this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/observability

Comment: As I understood the "Guide to app architecture" it's important to use a single stream for properties that are related to each other to avoid inconsistencies. Using "ObservableField" would require to use a stream for every property as I understand. Please read this: https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/ui-layer#additional-considerations